# Anchor tag not jumping to id

Tags: html, wordpress, anchor, sections

This is usually a basic thing to do, however suprisingly im having difficulties with it.

I got a link:

```
<a href="#maps678">t.b.a.</a>
```

That i want click to jump to the map section at the bottom of my page

```
<section id="maps678"> .... </section>
```

Ive added 678 to make sure its unique. I tried changing the 'section' to 'div' but none of it works. What could be preventing it from working?

Answer (score 2):

Your anchor and your ID are differents.

map**s**678

This will work:

```
<a href="#maps678">t.b.a.</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

spell mistake `maps678` to `#map678` you forget `'s'`

```
<a href="#maps678">t.b.a.</a>
```

Comment: Ah youre right thats what i get when i need to rush. However it still doesnt work. Could there be other factors that prevent it from working?

<a href="#maps678">t.b.a.</a>
<section id="maps678"></section>